# What is the white camera in Thelma And Louise '91?

Tags: camera, camera-identification

[In the '91 classic. Thelma And Louise. There is an white camera.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRx4QzEAWQY&t=1m34s)

Looks like some sort of Polaroid.

What is the name of that camera?

Comment: This is not exactly a good question but that camera looks like its came from the future of an 50's science fiction movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It's a Polaroid type 600 box camera**

Specifically, it's the Polaroid Cool Cam. This model was not actually white, but grey with pink front plates and a pink strap. Although the pink front isn't visible in the video, you can see the pink strap hanging from the camera.

[image]

These cameras shot Polaroid instant film, and many versions of this type were made (all of which **very** similar).

Comment: I had the normal (I suppose "non-cool") black version (with red front?)...

Comment: @BaardKopperud that was the cool cam as well. It was released in multiple colour schemes, and iirc this version (with "cool cam" on the flash unit) in two colour schemes.